# how to using e.HasMorePages With For Each

Tags: vb.net

i me using e.HasMorePages with code

```
For x As Integer = RowNo To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim mypen As New Pen(Color.Black, 6)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgv.Rows(x - 1).Cells(0).Value.ToString(), f, Brushes.Black, 645, yElementy)

    If RowNo Mod 6 = 0 Then
        RowNo += 1
        e.HasMorePages = True
        Exit For
     End If

     RowNo += 1
Next
```

how to using e.HasMorePages  With code

```
For Each myRow In dtn.Rows
    ListView1.Items.Add(n + ListView1.Items.Count + 1)
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(13).ToString())
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(5).ToString())
    ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(14).ToString())

    'i want to add here
Next
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `e.HasMorePages` in your code? The `e` is part of an event, not sure which event your first posted code is from, but I am not sure why you want to use an event value in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: You don't add items to a ListView in printing code.  It makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Typical layout:** count variable(class level) for remembering what position we are at in the items printing. I like a `List(Of String)` for looping and printing. Inside the printPage event you need to have a variable for what row(y axis) your printing the records to and increment it with each iteration. Since it's graphics based you can also use a [Rectangle](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=rectangle&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&ved=0CE8QFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.drawing.rectangle.aspx&ei=SxP8UdrzPK7iyAHrpIDgBg&usg=AFQjCNGHqQYGihBmggXg1cWqbltAxlGgtg&bvm=bv.50165853,d.aWc) structure and print contents to it using a [StringFormat](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=stringformat&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.drawing.stringformat.aspx&ei=GBP8UcfcCsWGyQGX0IHgAg&usg=AFQjCNEL0M-AIgPTbzpmSk8CPifT5ZHRgg&bvm=bv.50165853,d.aWc) object for text wrapping and layout.

[Print Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx)

*Example off the top of my head - not tested.*

```
Public Class Form1 ' your form name here
  Private count As Integer
  Private row As Integer
  Private Sub print_Page(...) Handles ...
    row = 100 'starting point from the top
    Using p As New Pen(Brushes.Bisque) 'self disposing graphics object
       'we use the variable here to know where we are if we have to go to next page
      Dim rowCount = dg.Rows.Count - 1
      For i As Integer = count To rowCount
        e.Graphics.DrawString({value},p, Font, x, y)
        row += 16 'basically the font height and some space in-between
        If row = e.MarginBounds.Bottom - 20 Then
          e.HasMorePages = True
          If i <> rowCount Then 'are we on the last row?
           count = i ' remember where we left off
           Exit Sub ' cause this event will fire again and we need to start over 
          End If
        End If
      Next
     End Using
   End Sub
   '...
End Class
```

Comment: This problem appeared     Using p As New Pen(Pens.Navy)          Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments

Answer (score 0):

Public Class frmTestHasMorePages

```
Dim Font12 As Font = New Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
Dim Font8 As Font = New Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
Dim sBrush As Drawing.Brush

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Static count As Integer
    Static topMargin As Integer = 50
    Static line As Integer
    Static s, z As Integer
    Dim linesPerPage = 65
    Dim lineCount = 350
    Static totalpages As Integer = IIf(lineCount Mod linesPerPage = 0, (lineCount / linesPerPage), (lineCount / linesPerPage) + 1)
    sBrush = Brushes.Black
    Dim pageBottom = e.PageBounds.Bottom

    For i As Integer = count To lineCount
        If z > lineCount Then
            sBrush = Brushes.Blue
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " & s + 1 & "/" & totalpages, Font8, sBrush, 750, pageBottom - 20)
            sBrush = Brushes.Red
            e.Graphics.DrawString("End of document ", Font8, sBrush, 50, pageBottom - 20)
            e.HasMorePages = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Testing hasmorepages with different options " & z, Font12, sBrush, 45, (i * 16) + topMargin)
        line += 15
        z += 1
        If i = linesPerPage AndAlso s <= totalpages Then

            e.HasMorePages = True
            sBrush = Brushes.Blue
            s += 1
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " & s & "/" & totalpages, Font8, sBrush, 750, pageBottom - 20)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Continued...", Font8, sBrush, 50, pageBottom - 20)
            i = 0
            If i <> lineCount Then  REM if it is the last line to print
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: This program has been tested thoroughly and works fine